# Continuously Running Script Crashes in EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, cpu-usage, tmux, gnu-screen, nohup

I am running Python scripts in several EC2 instances to scrape data and write it to an RDS instance every few minutes. I am running the scripts continuously as the data needs to be collected in real time. I ran the scripts in the EC2 console using `nohup python3 script.py &`. Using this method, I was able to collect data for several days, but 2 of my scripts have since crashed in the EC2 instance and are no longer running.

I looked at the EC2's CPU usage, and it looks like the CPU usage jumped up to about 40% right before these 2 scripts stopped executing (CPU usage is usually 7%). Because of the nature of the data I am collecting, there are big spikes in CPU usage for about 1 hour a day. However, the day before, CPU usage jumped up to 100% for 30 minutes but the scripts kept on running.

Can anyone advise how to keep a Python script running in an EC2 instance continuously? I know **tmux** and **screen** are options, but I am wondering if these will help solve the problem (i.e., avoid having the script stop executing in the EC2 console). I am also now planning to run the scripts in separate EC2 instances, because I think the spike in CPU usage might have caused them to crash. However, I don't fully understand what caused the scripts to crash or how I can ensure it won't happen again. Any help here would be appreciated.

As an aside, I prefer not to use Cron for this particular data collection job due to timing issues.

Comment: Does your script output a log file? Have you checked the contents of the log file?

Comment: Hi, no I didn't have the script output to a log file, but I can see from running the same script in screen that there was a "time out" error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this was caused by spikes in CPU usage that caused the EC2 instance to kill the script. I have since switched to using more EC2 instances with lower CPU usage on each and the scripts are running fine using **screen**.